# How to fetch an XML feed using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-7

I've decided to convert a Windows Phone 7 app that fetches an XML feed and then parses it to an asp.net web app, using Visual Web Developer Express. I figure since the code already works for WP7, it should be a matter of mostly copying and pasting it for the C# code behind.

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeConfig&a=sf-muni&r=" + line1);
```

That's the first line of code from my WP7 app that fetches the XML feed, but I can't even get HttpWebRequest to work in Visual Web Developer like that. Intellisense shows a create and createdefault, but no CreateHttp like there was in Windows Phone 7. I just need to figure out how to fetch the page, I assume the parsing will be the same as on my phone app. Any help?

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102865/asp-net-load-xml-file-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be easier to use.

`WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("url");`

Answer (score 0):

Just call `WebRequest.Create()`.
You may need to cast the result to `HttpWebRequest`.

Note that the `WebClient` class makes this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Asp.Net Rss Toolkit found here: http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/ It is a neat tool that will allow you to consume rss feeds. You can use their command line interface to create your c# or vb.net class with all of the property of your feed, therefore you don't have to parse anything. I totally recommend it.